# CIFaceFeature is detecting only one face

Tags: swift, xcode

The problem is that my code is working only for one face. If I take a photo of two faces, it won't detect the second one, and the same for more than two faces. Here is my code:

```
if let inputImage = imageView.image {
        let ciImage = CIImage(CGImage: inputImage.CGImage!)

        let options = [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh]
        let faceDetector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: nil, options: options)

        let faces = faceDetector.featuresInImage(ciImage)

        if let face = faces.first as? CIFaceFeature {
            print("Found face at \(face.bounds)")

            if face.hasLeftEyePosition {
                print("Found left eye at \(face.leftEyePosition)")
            }

            if face.hasRightEyePosition {
                print("Found right eye at \(face.rightEyePosition)")
            }

            if face.hasMouthPosition {
                print("Found mouth at \(face.mouthPosition)")
            }
        }
        print("\(faces.count)")
    }
```

Comment: `if let face = faces.first` Indeed, there's only one face because *you* only work on the first face. ;)

Comment: @EricD so I need to fix it by running a loop until counting the number of faces is finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you only work on the first face found, because of this:

```
if let face = faces.first as? CIFaceFeature {
```

---

So for example, instead, you could use a loop and iterate over the array, like this:

```
for item in faces {
    if let face = item as? CIFaceFeature {
        print("Found face at \(face.bounds)")

        if face.hasLeftEyePosition {
            print("Found left eye at \(face.leftEyePosition)")
        }

        if face.hasRightEyePosition {
            print("Found right eye at \(face.rightEyePosition)")
        }

        if face.hasMouthPosition {
            print("Found mouth at \(face.mouthPosition)")
        }
    }
}
```

Or like this, slightly better:

```
if let faces = faceDetector.featuresInImage(ciImage) as? [CIFaceFeature] {
    for face in faces {
        print("Found face at \(face.bounds)")

        if face.hasLeftEyePosition {
            print("Found left eye at \(face.leftEyePosition)")
        }

        if face.hasRightEyePosition {
            print("Found right eye at \(face.rightEyePosition)")
        }

        if face.hasMouthPosition {
            print("Found mouth at \(face.mouthPosition)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx a lot! You helped me to fix the problem